# How do I remove old powershell from windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

Namaste all experienced windows superusers,

I am tinkering around with PowerShell. I don't understand why windows is making it difficult by not letting us not completely replace the legacy PowerShell that comes with the installation.

It is stuck at version 5 I think, unable to update, delete and so on. I'm currently using PowerShell 7, but it bugs me when the old version keeps showing up at various places. Like, the **WIN+X** keys and so on.

Can I completely get rid of the old PowerShell version?? Or is it required for some functionality?

Comment: version 5.1 is built into windows ... DO NOT remove it. [*grin*] there are several things that require it. all versions after 5.1 are cross-platform versions and don't always have all the same things. **_there is a reason that v6+ installs side-by-side._**

Answer (score 4):

***'Can I completely get rid of the old PowerShell version??'***

Simply put, you can't, it's part of the OS, meaning packaged in .Net full. Virtually all of Windows uses it, and you cannot manage other Windows solutions without it. Well, you can, but only via GUI. Yet, several aspects can only be done via PowerShell.

***Powershell.exe, powershell_ise.exe, is not PowerShell,*** they are just shells that allow PowerShell to run or code (interactive/scripts, etc.) to be created
and used/executed.

***I do not need either (powpershell.exe/powershell_ise.exe) to run PowerShell code.*** Anyone can write their own PowerShell/shell host by calling directly into .Net libraries that Powershell.exe/PowerShell_ise.exe depends/is based on.

For Example:

https://bank-security.medium.com/how-to-running-powershell-commands-without-powershell-exe-a6a19595f628

To get recent versions of Windows PowerShell, you must install.Net package that it is bundled with. Windows requires .Net, so, hence my statement.

WinPS will be part of the OS just like cmd.exe/wscript.exe/cscript.exe/wmic.exe are, for the foreseeable future as per Microsoft announcements/docs; though WinPS, is not getting any future work. What it is today, is what it will be forever.

All work is focused on .Net Core/Powershell core, which will not be part of the OS because it is OSS and cross-platform. Thus always a side-by-side install on Windows relative to WinPS.

You can only uninstall versions on a system where you upgraded from a previous version.

[Powershell version history](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/#:%7E:text=PowerShell%20and%20Windows%20versions%20%5E%20%20%20PowerShell,R2%20SP1%20...%20%204%20more%20rows)

**.NetCore (PSCore), is not an upgrade from/for/to WinPS, it is a new thing and a new frontier.**

Lastly, since virtually every major network hardware, systems management, security vendors, etc.,  includes PowerShell modules to work with automating their stuff, trying to drop it means you will have additional issues. Not all vendors on up to date to lever PowerShell Core/.Net Core.

So, ***if you are really saying, you really want to remove legacy WinPS, that means completely removing all of .Net libraries associated with it full off your system,*** and that obviously is not a thing as it will virtually break all of Windows.

Lastly, anything I can do with PS, I can do with VBS/WMIC, which is how things were done before PowerShell ([formerly Monad](http://www.jsnover.com/Docs/MonadManifesto.pdf)) ever existed.

***Proper risk management/security, if this is the reason for your post, is proper logging, auditing, active response, use restriction, boundary control, etc.***

But hey,  u do u, as only you have to deal with the consequences of your decisions.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain.